# Почему перестала работать вибрация на ios 13?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

После обновления ios до 13 версии,в игре перестала полностью работать вибрация. Для того чтобы протестировать в чем проблема я создал отдельную сцену и использовал - Handheld.Vibrate() и это не сработало .Подскажите пожалуйста в чем
может быть проблема.Я использую Unity версии - 2018.2.21f.

Comment: Потому, что haptic feedback...

Comment: @Yaroslav  Подскажите пожалуйста что вы имеете в виду ?

Comment: Я имел ввиду haptic feedback. Если это что-то не знакомое, тогда `Ok Google: haptic feedback что это`

Comment: Вроде как на девайсах ios 13+ нет вибраторов (я знаю только, что у топового точно нет). Если я не ошибаюсь на Unity ещё не поддерживает. Придётся написать класс на ObjC.

Comment: @Yaroslav спасибо огромное за помощь

Comment: @Yaroslav будьте добры, оформите ответ :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker добры? Я же не добрый. Я местный злюка:)